# Mocked func returning promise with callFake doesn't enter then()

Tags: angularjs, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have same method calls and am trying to write tests to mock `MyService.getSoemthing` in methodB(). However, it doesn't seem to work..

```
methodA(): any {
    methodB().then(() => {
        do something...
    })
}

methodB(): ng.IPromise<void> {
    return MyService.getSomething(a,b,c,d,e).then((result) => {
        ...does something with result...
        doesn't returning anything
    });
}

// With MyServiceMock injected
spyOn(MyServiceMock, 'getSomething').and.callFake(() => {
    return $q.resolve(result); // result is a variable that has already been init
});

or 

spyOn(MyServiceMock, 'getSomething').and.callFake((a,b,c,d,e) => {
    return $q.resolve(result); // result is a variable that has already been init
});

// then I call my methodA and ..
methodA();
```

It simply won't work.. I am able to debug until the resolution of the mock, it gets to resolve the promise but never ends up inside my ** ...does something with result... **

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like the good old angular testing peculiarity where $q in a testing context needs to have $timeout.flush() called so that $q-made promises actually resolve. Might try adding a $timeout.flush() after your methodA() call inside the relevant it()s.

Comment: That's exactly what it was! Thanks a lot!